# Windows/Linux HDD benchmark

Tags: kvm-virtualization, hard-drive, benchmark

I'm going to compare, how windows virtual machines are working in QEMU/KVM environment and IO performance loss. So I want to measure HDD performance in Linux host and Windows VM. Is there any benchmarking tool you can advise, that is working both on Linux/Windows?

Answer (score 2):

Comparing performance between an host and a guest in my opinion doesn't make much sense, we are talking about two different things .

However you can try with hdparm that should work also on windows.

Comment: Why? I have a a greate performance loss when running database patterns in VM. As we know, database patterns are mostly depends on IO operations. I want to check if the KVM's virtio driver is the bottleneck comparing its performance to virtio less mode. Do you have any other ideas to check, where is the bottleneck? Hddparm is not a benchmarking tool, it can only measure some read operations.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is also interested to measure the difference between the HDD performance in Linux host system and Windows VMs, the best way I've find is free tool http://iometer.org. For Linux it has only "server" part, but you can launch windows client from the Windows VM. Great advantage is that there is a possibility to implement different usage patterns, for example web-server or database ones. It's able to set block size, ratio between read/write operations, sequential and random access, etc.

Answer (score -1):

bonnie++ is a good tool for measuring disk speed. It sould run on Windows with cygwin.